# PTP but not MTP

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy Express with Android 4.1.2. When I connect my phone over USB, it connects as a media device. The only option I see is Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP): I cannot choose MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). Is that expected, and if not what could fix it?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93101/unable-to-write-to-internal-storage-through-mtp

Comment: Maybe https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/  "Connect your smartphone or tablet to your computer with a USB cable. Change the USB mode to “file transfer (MTP)” mode".  So maybe an option called "File Transfer"?  On my android phone it has "File transfer,  USB tethering, MIDI, PTP, No data transfer"